# Is there any option to register user as vendor in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am planning to setup an e-commerce platform on which vendors can come, register, upload and sell their products.

Want to know is there any option to register a user as a vendor in Broadleaf.
I have deployed site and admin webapp, but as of now I can't find any option for that.

Please let me know if Broadleaf commerce can be the choice of required scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are after Multi Tenant functionality which Broadleaf offers in the Enterprise version.

Comment: Hi, Phillipuniverse :Thanks for the reply. But I guess downloaded the Enterprise version but its not showing me any option to register as a vendor. How to confirm the same?

Comment: Hey Amit, if you already have purchased Broadleaf multi-tenant functionality then you should direct your questions to support AT broadleafcommerce.com.

Comment: I was trying the community support version and that doesn't have multi-tenant functionality, got to know later and was looking for an open source framework that support the same functionality.